# Adding active class for nav link in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, next.js

I am using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and want to add an active class to a nav link when the page it links to matches the url. But I also want it to be active when the url is deeper than only the page.

For example, a nav link to `/register` would be "active" for:

- `/register`
- `/register/sign-up`

Comment: What is next.js? obviously a JavaScript file, but it could literally contain anything, how is anyone supposed to help based on the little information provided in your post?

Comment: @SPlatte. https://nextjs.org/. I thought it was obvious with it being so well known in the industry.

Comment: Not to anyone not familiar with react.  Have you tried embedding the URI in an iframe?

Comment: No. I think that would be overkill. I have used this and it works fine (https://flaviocopes.com/nextjs-active-link/), But only for one layer. It doesn't work for deeper segmented urls @SPlatten

Answer (score 7):

Here's a `NavLink` component I wrote for Next.js. It has the same API as `Link`, with the addition of two props:

- an `activeClassName` that will be applied to the link when it matches
- (optional) `exact` - prevents matching “deeper” routes)

```js
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function NavLink({ href, as, exact, activeClassName, children, ...props }) {
  const { asPath } = useRouter();
  // Normalize and split paths into their segments
  const segment = (p) => new URL(p, 'http://example.com').pathname.split('/').filter(s => s);
  const currentPath = segment(asPath);
  const targetPath = segment(as || href);
  // The route is active if all of the following are true:
  //   1. There are at least as many segments in the current route as in the destination route
  //   2. The current route matches the destination route
  //   3. If we're in “exact" mode, there are no extra path segments at the end
  const isActive = currentPath.length >= targetPath.length
    && targetPath.every((p, i) => currentPath[i] === p)
    && (!exact || targetPath.length === currentPath.length);

  const child = React.Children.only(children);
  const className = ((child.props.className || '') + ' ' + (isActive ? activeClassName : '')).trim();

  return (
    <Link href={href} as={as} {...props}>
      {React.cloneElement(child, { className })}
    </Link>
  );
}
```

It's possible to make this simpler and more robust by relying on the route-matching functionality from the [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) module, which is already a dependency of Next.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { pathToRegexp } from 'path-to-regexp';

export default function NavLink({ href, as, exact, activeClassName, children, ...props }) {
  const { asPath } = useRouter();
  const isActive = pathToRegexp(as || href, [], { sensitive: true, end: !!exact }).test(asPath);

  const child = React.Children.only(children);
  const className = ((child.props.className || '') + ' ' + (isActive ? activeClassName : '')).trim();

  return (
    <Link href={href} as={as} {...props}>
      {React.cloneElement(child, { className })}
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I built on [an example in the nextjs docs](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/active-class-name/components/ActiveLink.tsx) and [a little bit of what's in the react-router-dom source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/b67538b1172c3dcf07a2e431bbe7c2eb32b06eaf/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L547) to come up with this

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link, { LinkProps } from "next/link";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

type Props = LinkProps & {
  className?: string;
  activeClassName: string;
  children?:
    | React.ReactNode
    | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
};

export default function NavLink({
  children,
  activeClassName,
  className,
  ...props
}: Props) {
  const { asPath, isReady } = useRouter();
  const [computedClassName, setComputedClassName] = useState(className);

  // Dynamic route will be matched via props.as
  // Static route will be matched via props.href
  const linkPathname = new URL(
    (props.as || props.href) as string,
    location.href
  ).pathname;

  // Using URL().pathname to get rid of query and hash
  const activePathname = new URL(asPath, location.href).pathname;

  const isActive = linkPathname === activePathname;

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if the router fields are updated client-side
    if (isReady) {
      const newClassName = isActive
        ? `${className} ${activeClassName}`.trim()
        : className;

      if (newClassName !== computedClassName) {
        setComputedClassName(newClassName);
      }
    }
  }, [
    asPath,
    isReady,
    props.as,
    props.href,
    activeClassName,
    className,
    computedClassName,
    isActive,
  ]);

  return (
    <Link className={computedClassName} {...props}>
      {typeof children === "function" ? children({ isActive }) : children}
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about previous versions, but for Next.JS 14.*, it's much simpler to implement.

```
'use client'
import { useSelectedLayoutSegment } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function MyNavBar() {
  const segment = useSelectedLayoutSegment()
 
  return (
     <div>
        <Link className={segment == null   ? styles.active : "")} href="/">    Home</Link>
        <Link className={segment == 'info' ? styles.active : "")} href="/info">Info</Link>
   </div>
  )}
```

You can compare the segment var to the Link entry href you're on, or to null for home.

Note that this forces you to make the navBar a client component.

Note also that there's a way to look at more than one navigation layer. This is explained in the documentation as well.

See the documentation here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-selected-layout-segment